# CSS: Maintain aspect ratio in responsive img with max-width and max-height

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design

<sub>(Similar questions are already asked at stackoverflow, but this question has more constraints, such as both a specific max-width, max-height, a required specific height and width, and no layout shift.)</sub>

## Problem:

I want to have a responsive image with the following constraints:

- max-width: 100%, so that it doesn't overflow to the right, and that it is responsive when reducing the screen width.
- max-height: 200px, so that large images are reduced in rendered dimensions.
- height and width html attributes set, so that the browser can precalculate the required image dimensions, so that the layout doesn't shift/move elements beside/below the image, while the image is loading. (To reduce the [cumulative layout shift](https://web.dev/optimize-cls/).)
- image aspect ratio should stay 1:1
- no extra margins should be created around the image
- the image should be rendered with a plain html img tag, not with css background-images
- the image should not be rendered in a larger dimension than its original dimension

How can I achieve this with CSS?

(If CSS cannot achieve this, then maybe in JavaScript?)

## What I tried

I tried several CSS features, such as [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) and max-width: 100% etc, but I always get at least one of the contraints failing while trying to fix another constraint. For example, object-fit creates margins/paddings for the image when it's reduced in size when the screen size reduces, as if the image border isn't reduced. This is demonstrated in the following code:

https://codepen.io/Devabc/pen/mdVvyKq

```css
/* Should appear to the right of the Wombat */

.beside {
  float: left;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
}


/* Should appear below the Wombat */

.below {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  clear: both;
}

img {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  
  /* Without this, aspect ratio is not normal. 
But with this, it creates an unwanted margin. */
  object-fit: scale-down;
  object-position: left;
}
```

```html
<img 
height="533" 
width="799" 
src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/18/Vombatus_ursinus_-Maria_Island_National_Park.jpg/800px-Vombatus_ursinus_-Maria_Island_National_Park.jpg" 
/>

<div class="beside">This text should be directly to the right of the Wombat, without any margin between the Wombat and this text.</div>

<div class="below">This text should be directly below the Wombat, without any margin between this and the Wombat. 
The dimensions of the original Wombat img are:
width: 799px, height: 533px</div>
```

(The green text should be to the right of the Wombat, without margin. But object-fit causes a padding/margin to appear with the length of the original image.)

It's feels almost as if this isn't possible with CSS, even though these requirements shouldn't be too much to ask nowadays, with responsive design being important.

How can I fix this with HTML/CSS?

Comment: Hey, hopping in real quick to check whether I solved your issue or do I need to ameliorate my skills?

Answer (score 4):

I've been struggling with this for years on end, but just today I figured a way to do it when you know the image's aspect ratio, hope it helps:

Start by defining a `--img-ratio` [CSS custom property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) in the `img` element corresponding to the image's `height / width` ratio.

```html
<!-- example of a square image (height / width = 1) -->
<img src="..." style="--img-ratio: 1" />
```

Knowing that our desired max-height is 200px (or you could go with a generic `--max-height`), we know 2 variables of the equation:

```
ratio = height / width
width = height * ratio
```

Applying this:

```css
img {
  --max-height: 200px;
  /* Set a baseline width for your element */
  width: 100%;
  /* And limit it with our function above (pick 100% with min() if this size is bigger than parent's width to prevent overflowing) */
  max-width: min(100%, calc(var(--max-height, 200px) * var(--img-ratio, 1)));
}
```

And there we go! This should work to limit the height without extra margins even in complicated flex layouts.

Let me know if this answer is unclear, hope it helps

PS: If you can't know the ratio of the image beforehand, than maybe JS is indeed your only option - I'm yet to find an alternative

Comment: This is a brilliant solution for responsive images when you know the aspect ratio before writing the output (which I do). Have an upvote, thanks! You can improve it further by adding min(100%, calc...) so it doesn't get beyond available width).

Answer (score 0):

> If CSS cannot achieve this, then maybe in JavaScript?

I wouldn't solve this with JavaScript. I understand you want to use `width` & `height` on `img` elements to mitigate content layout shifts, but in this case since you must have a `max-height` of `200px` on the image, it will cause issues on images with larger `natural width`. The space you see between the green text & the Wombat is not `margin` or `padding`, it is that actual [content width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model) which you have defined as `799px`.
You can solve this with a bit of preparation on the data you wish to present to the user. Prepare your `width` as you would expect what your image `width` would be. `width=799` in this case is unrealistic because the image will not respond as far as that because of the `max-height:200px` limitation - same case with `height=533`. The whole point of using static measurements such as unit pixels is you are already declaring that this X element will just take Y space.

```
<img 
    height="200" 
    width="300" 
    src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/18/Vombatus_ursinus_-Maria_Island_National_Park.jpg/800px-Vombatus_ursinus_-Maria_Island_National_Park.jpg" 
/>
```

Comment: So I should adjust the img `height` and `width` based on the preferred max-height instead of using the original image dimensions. I can do that, but when I reduce the screen width, I stil get either an aspect ratio problem when not using `object-fit`, or I get white space content below the wombat when using `object-fit`.

Comment: You can still use `object-fit`. Regarding your issue on small screens producing "white space" just do `img {height:auto;}` on relevant screen sizes. I also recommend implementing a loading screen for your website if you are really set on mitigating content layout shift - such that if all assets (not just images) are loaded, remove the loading screen. Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

If your problem is that your webpage/website is not responsive, so I would suggest you to use **Viewport Units** like `vw` for **width** and `vh` for **height** instead of `px` or `%` for all your elements including **border** and **font-size** because it will help you make your webpage/website responsive.

It should solve your issue but if it doesn't let me know in the comments, I will try my best to help you.